# Flutter dynamic text in RawMaterialButton

Tags: flutter, dart, button, widget

I am creating my own style button in flutter. So far I created a `commonui.dart` file and placed the following code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton({@required this.onPressed});
  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      fillColor: Colors.green,
      splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: const <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 10.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Tap Me",
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'ActoBold'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,

    );
  }
}
```

And calling it from my pages like this

```
CustomButton(
     onPressed: () {
        print("Tapped Me");
      },
)
```

I would likes to make the button text dynamic. How to pass the variable to the `CustomButton` widget ?

Comment: why don't you do  print(variablename); while calling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like you just did for the onPressed function. Only difference is that the type will be String.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  final String buttonText;

  CustomButton({@required this.onPressed, this.buttonText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      fillColor: Colors.green,
      splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: const <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 10.0,
            ),
            Text(
              buttonText ?? 'Tap me',
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'ActoBold'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can pass your value to CustomButton.

```
CustomButton(
   buttonText: 'Updated Text',
   onPressed: () {
      print("Tapped Me");
   },
)
```

If you want to change the value dynamically when you click the button, use a stateful widget:

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  String _buttonText;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomButton(
        buttonText: _buttonText,
        onPressed: () {
          print("Tap Me");
          setState(() {
            _buttonText = 'Tapped';
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following changes...

```
CustomButton(
child: Text(trigger),
 onPressed: () {
    setState((){
          trigger="tapped me";
})
  },
)
```

dont forget to declare variable and change your class stateless to stateful widget.